# are all talene into the database - it should do so only with a number

Tags: php, mysqli

that's how I'm making my own little "like" system for my website, this is how when I click "like" then throw it all id into the database so it means that I have 1, 2 , 3, 4, and 5, so if for example, I click on 5 so smidre on all the others into the database even though I did not click on them.

so the problem is that it throws some numbers into the database which I have not looked

```
    $sql = "SELECT bruger.fornavn, bruger.efternavn, bruger.img, wall.id, wall.tekst, wall.brugerid, wall.opret_dag FROM wall JOIN bruger ON wall.brugerid=bruger.id ORDER BY `wall`.`id` DESC";
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql))
{ 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($fornavn, $efternavn, $img, $id, $tekst, $brugerid, $opret_dag);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
    ?>
    <div class="statwall">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <div class="wallindhold">
            <?php               
            echo $tekst;
            ?>
        </div>
            <?php
            if($_SESSION["login"] != false and $_SESSION["rank"] == 1)
            {
            ?>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="like" value="Synes godt om" id="likebutton">
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST["like"]))
                {
                    if($stm = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO wallLike (getid, brugerid, dato_time) VALUES (?, ?, now())' ))
                    {
                        $stm->bind_param('ss', $getid, $brugerid);
                        $getid = $id;
                        $brugerid = $_SESSION["id"];
                        $stm->execute();

                        echo "No Error!";

                        $stm->close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

The problem is that it throws all the numbers into the database. what I want to only throw a number into the database possibly the figures that I have clicked.

Comment: You are checking the same thing every time around the loop  (`if(isset($_POST["like"]))`). You need to compare the value that the user liked with the particular item that time around the loop (`$id`).

Comment: @IMSoP Do you want one example of what you mean completely?

Comment: Try putting this just before `if(isset($_POST["like"]))`, and you may see what I mean: `echo "id is $id; I am checking if \$_POST['like'] is set.<br/>";`

Comment: @IMSoP there will be a number on the area if you can call it

Comment: The value of `$_POST['like']` doesn't change in different parts of the page. PHP creates the whole page, then the user clicks "Synes godt om", then PHP creates the whole page again. So `if(isset($_POST["like"]))` will always be true if the user has clicked on any of the buttons.

Comment: @IMSoP Unfortunately I can not see quite what you mean.

Comment: Add `echo 'The value of $_POST["like"] is ' . $_POST["like"];` to the very beginning of your file. Add it anywhere you like. It will always say the same thing. You echo lots of forms, but they are *all exactly the same*, so clicking a different form creates the same values.

Comment: @IMSoP It comes up and says "synes godt om"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page currently has lots of forms, but they are all exactly the same. Whichever one you click, the values you get will be the same, so the same thing will happen. You check if *a* form has been submitted here:

```
if(isset($_POST["like"]))
```

But there is nothing to tell *which* form was submitted. So if a form was submitted, that will always be `true`, and the code will insert things into the database.

First, you need to make your forms different in some way. For instance, add a hidden input with the value of `$id` in:

```
        ?>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="like" value="Synes godt om" id="likebutton">
            <input type="hidden" name="like_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        </form>
        <?php
```

Second, you need to check which form was submitted:

```
 if( isset($_POST["like"]) && $_POST["like_id"] == $id )
```

Note that you could have two completely separate loops, one displaying the forms, and one processing the database `INSERT`s after the form has been submitted. This is often recommended, because it makes it clearer when different things are happening.